# Is Nabaat a good final choice for a SAB?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm toying with the decision to purchase and recruit Nabaat for my SAB role.  I prefer to have 'character' members as opposed to monster members, but it is somehow difficult to find much information about how good she is compared with other top SAB types.  Her Feral Link sounds quite good, but again it is hard to find any hard facts about how much damage one can expect to achieve.

Is it possible to infuse her to being one of the best SABs with any success?  Or is it a waste of time and money?

Answer (score 1):

Nabaat is a perfectly good choice as an endgame SAB. Her locked abilities are not bad and she has more hp than the black chocobo. She has good attack and magic stats and her feral link can be very damaging although it removes all debuffs afterwards. As another bonus she works for pack mentality with other human characters ex. lightning,sazh, amodar. She is a wonderful SAB overall but there is nothing saying you cant do fine with just a black chocobo if you want to save some cash. If you do chose to buy her go all potent and look up a good infusion build.